# Javascript - regex test() returns true but not all character match (even with ^...$)

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to do some input validation in a textarea:

```
const re= /^[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÿ\s\’\'\:\.\-\,\!\[\]\(\)\@\&\?]+?$/im;
re.test(control.value)
```

first test:

```
+
```

returns false, so far so good

second test:

```
+
1234
```

test() returns true, while it should keep returning false since it still contains an invalid character and I use ^...$

please enlight me on this

regards

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `m` flag - it matches the start and end of the *line*, not the start and end of the *string*. So, with your current code, if *one* line passes, the whole regex will pass.

To fix it, include newlines in your character set (if you indeed want to permit them), and remove the `m` flag, so that your `^` and `$` will match the beginning and end of the string *only*:

```js
const re= /^[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÿ\s\’\'\:\.\-\,\!\[\]\(\)\@\&\?\n]+?$/i;
const validate = str => re.test(str);
document.querySelector('textarea').onchange = function() {
  console.log(re.test(this.value));
}
```

```html
<textarea>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/BG1yZ3/1). You have added `m` flag. It means `^ and $ matches start and end of line`